# Group array by nested array

Tags: ruby, grouping

I have an array in this format:

```
[ 
  { day: 1
    intervals: [
      {
        from: 900,
        to: 1200
      }
    ]
  },
  { day: 2
    intervals: [
      {
        from: 900,
        to: 1200
      }
    ]
  },
  { day: 3
    intervals: [
      {
        from: 900,
        to: 1200
      }
    ]
  },
  { day: 4
    intervals: [
      {
        from: 900,
        to: 1200
      }
    ]
  },
  { day: 5
    intervals: [
      {
        from: 900,
        to: 1200
      }
    ]
  },
  { day: 6
    intervals: [
      {
        from: 900,
        to: 1200
      },
      {
        from: 1300,
        to: 2200
      }
    ]
  },
  { day: 7
    intervals: [
      {
        from: 900,
        to: 1200
      },
      {
        from: 1300,
        to: 2200
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I wan't to group them like this:

```
[ 
  { day: 1-5
    intervals: [
      {
        from: 900,
        to: 1200
      }
    ]
  },
  { day: 6-7
    intervals: [
      {
        from: 900,
        to: 1200
      },
      {
        from: 1300,
        to: 2200
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

### Criteria:

- Only group if intervals are the same.
- Only group if matches are in chronological order, i.e 1-5 or 1-3, not 1-2-5.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Note that your example output does not fulfill the 2nd requirement. `6-7` is only 2 days.

Comment: Oh, you're right! Deleted that criteria. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a variation of @joelparkerhenderson's solution that tries to be a bit closer to your requirements re formatting of the output etc.

```
output = []

grouped = input.group_by do |x|
  x[:intervals]
end

grouped.each_pair do |k, v|
  days = v.map {|day| day[:day]}
  if days.each_cons(2).all? { |d1, d2| d1.next == d2 }
    output << {
      :days => days.values_at(0,-1).join('-'),
      :intervals => k
    }
  end
end

puts output
```

Comment: If days 1, 2, 3, 5 have the same intervals, your code will not group 1-3, right?

Comment: True enough, this certainly can be improved.

Comment: I found this to be the best starting point for my problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This produces the required output:

```
by_interval = data.inject({}) do | a, e |
  i = e[:intervals]
  a[i] ||= []
  a[i] << e[:day].to_i
  a
end

result = by_interval.map do | interval, days |
  slices = days.sort.inject([]) do | a, e |
    a << [] if a == [] || a.last.last != e - 1
    a.last << e
    a
  end
  slices.map do | slice |
      {:day => "#{slice.first}-#{slice.last}", :intervals => interval }
  end
end
result.flatten!
```

I'm sure there are better approaches :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into [Map Method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map) for an array. You need to remap the array and iterate over it to extract the data you want using your "grouping" logic above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I do know about map/collect, Having trouble comparing all the day hashes with each other though.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Michael Kohl's answer

```
output = []

grouped = schedules.as_json.group_by do |x|
  x['intervals']
end

grouped.each_pair do |k, v|
  days = v.map {|day| day['day']}
  grouped_days = days.inject([[]]) do |grouped, num|
    if grouped.last.count == 0 or grouped.last.last == num - 1
      grouped.last << num
    else
      grouped << [ num ]
    end
    grouped
  end

  grouped_days.each do |d|
    output << {
      heading: d.values_at(0, -1).uniq.join('-'),
      interval: k
    }
  end
end

output
```

You should probably split that up into separate methods, but you get the idea.